# showing wait view till image-filtering in progress

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

Hello guys (My first question here I think :)),

I am new to Swift and iOS programming. I am doing image-filtering and I am trying to use `UIActivityIndicatorView` for the waiting time till filtered image is loaded. The activity indicator is enclosed in a another view with text label: "Filtering in Progress". However the wait view does not appear.

With debug, I noticed that the view is not instantly updated after a line of code is executed; view is updated after the whole block is executed. So, in this case, the following code is not working:

```
showActivityView()  //shows the view with text and spinner
filteredImageView.image = imageProcessor.clearFilters().addFilter(currentFilter).filter() //shows filtered image on image view
hideActivityView() //hides the view with text and spinner
```

This does not work because, I guess, the whole view is updated after hideActivityView() is completed. Any idea of how to implement this in a clean way.

Also it would be nice to have some good related references if someone knows. I am trying to find myself but with no luck so far.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use an async dispatch with a callback to to the filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the hint. I read a lot about this concept today. So, I create a queue first:

`var waitQueue: dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_queue_create("waiter", nil)`

And then put all filtering jobs to queue.. as described in mad_manny's solution.

```
let activityView = showActivityView("Filter in Progress..")
dispatch_async(waitQueue) {
self.currentFilter = filter.changeIntensity((filter.MIN_INTENSITY+filter.MAX_INTENSITY)/2)                
self.filteredImage = self.imageProcessor.clearFilters().addFilter(self.currentFilter).filter()                
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {                    
  self.filteredImageView.image = self.filteredImage                    
  self.hideActivityView(activityView)                    
  self.showFilteredImage()                
  }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoud do the filtering in another thread. You can do this by using *Grand Central Dispatch* ([tutorial here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1)).
Your code would look similar to the following:

```
showActivityView()  //shows the view with text and spinner
var image: UIImage?

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0), {

    image = imageProcessor.clearFilters().addFilter(currentFilter).filter() //shows filtered image on image view

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_mein_queue(), {
        filteredImageView.image = image!
        hideActivityView() //hides the view with text and spinner
    }

}
```